# Error while trying to upgrade pods on GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to upgrade pods on GKE and receiving this error:

The request contains invalid arguments: "EXTERNAL: bad desired node version (1.7.6-gke.1).". Error code: "7"

The pods are running version 1.7.5

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in allowing 1.7.6-gke.1 as a node version. For me, selecting 1.7.6 upgraded correctly.

Comment: yes, it also worked for me going to 1.7.6 but the 1.7.6-gke.1 still raises the error above